# `kubectl get hpa` showing targets as unknown and not autoscaling the pod when the load is increased?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I create a deployment and one HPA for that deployment (single node minikube cluster). But when I run the `kubectl get hpa`, it shows the targets as unknown (screenshot below)

```
NAME       REFERENCE             TARGETS        MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
producer   Deployment/producer   <unknown>/1%   1         3         1          42m
```

Below is the deployment.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.1.0 (36652f6)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: producer
  name: producer
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: producer
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <image name>
        name: producer
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8090
        env:
        - name: mongoUrl
          value: mongodb://mongo:27017
        - name: mongoHost
          value: mongo
        - name: mongoPort
          value: "27017"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 10m
         resources: {}
       restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

I run `kubectl autoscale deployment producer --cpu-percent=1 --min=1 --max=3` command for setting the autoscaler for the producer deployment. Below is the output for `kubectl describe hpa` :

```
Type     Reason                        Age                 From                       Message
  ----     ------                        ----                ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  43m (x13 over 49m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: missing request for cpu on container producer in pod default/producer-c7dd566f6-69gbq
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       4m (x91 over 49m)   horizontal-pod-autoscaler  missing request for cpu on container producer in pod default/producer-c7dd566f6-69gbq
```

I have already enabled the `heapster` and `metrics-server` addons on minikube and waiting the hpa is running from the last 30 minutes.

Logs from `kube-controller-manager` in minikube:

```
{"log":"I0912 10:36:40.806224       1 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:\"HorizontalPodAutoscaler\", Namespace:\"default\", Name:\"producer\", UID:\"135d0ebc-b671-11e8-a19f-080027646864\", APIVersion:\"autoscaling/v2beta1\", ResourceVersion:\"71101\", FieldPath:\"\"}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedGetResourceMetric' missing request for cpu on container producer in pod default/producer-c7dd566f6-w8zcd\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-09-12T10:36:40.80645916Z"}
{"log":"I0912 10:36:40.806511       1 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:\"HorizontalPodAutoscaler\", Namespace:\"default\", Name:\"producer\", UID:\"135d0ebc-b671-11e8-a19f-080027646864\", APIVersion:\"autoscaling/v2beta1\", ResourceVersion:\"71101\", FieldPath:\"\"}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'FailedComputeMetricsReplicas' failed to get cpu utilization: missing request for cpu on container producer in pod default/producer-c7dd566f6-w8zcd\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2018-09-12T10:36:40.806564094Z"}
```

Output from `kubectl top nodes`

```
NAME       CPU(cores)   CPU%      MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
minikube   336m         16%       1518Mi          19%
```

I have tried setting the `horizontal-pod-autoscaler-use-rest-clients=false` for `kube-controller-manager`, still facing the same issue.

Comment: Which version kubernetes and heapster?

Comment: heapster version: 1.5.3, minikube version: 0.28.2, kubectl version: 1.11

Comment: Could you try to run `kubectl autoscale deployment producer --cpu-percent=10 --min=1 --max=3`
looks like 1% is too small for HPA

Comment: @NickRak tried with cpu percentage 10 and 40, still having the same issue.

Comment: what's the output of `kubectl top nodes`?

Comment: @Rico   updated the question with the result of `kubectl top nodes`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was with my `producer-deployment.yaml` as I had overwritten the resources request to be null again by writing the line: `resources: {}` after

```
resources:
    requests:
        cpu: 10m
```

This made my resources request null and that is why heapster was showing `missing request for cpu on container producer`.

removing the line `resources: {}` form `producer-deployment.yaml` solved the issue.

Comment: This solved my problem with the cpu as unknown. This is on 1.11.x